# Regex match till the first > and then search again

Tags: android, html, regex

I'm trying to change some HTML text using regex, I have this:

```
<font class="Apple-style-span" color="#0036ff">This is a text</font>
```

Using this regex: `.replaceAll("(<font.+)\\S*color+.*?(>)","<span class=\"c2f\">");`

It became: `<span class="c2f">This is a text</span>`(i use another regex to change )

But the problem happens when I have nested font like this:

```
<font class="Apple-style-span" color="#0036ff">This is a text AND <font class="Apple-style-span" color="#0036ff">This is Edited TOOO</font></font>
```

It became: `<span class="c2f">This is Edited TOOO</span></span>`(changed /font using replace too)

I can understand why it happens, but I don't know how to make it match each tag.

What I want:

```
<span class="c2f">This is a text AND <span class="c2f">This is Edited TOOO</span></span>
```

Is this possible or I need another "approach"?

Comment: Have you considered using an actual HTML parser, rather than [attempting to use a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/115145)?

Comment: @CommonsWare actually i do, but sometimes i will receive only some paragraphs with edited lines, but now you said, is it possible to Jsoup parse only a small part of html? i will try =x thank you

Comment: I have not used JSoup specifically. However, usually HTML parsers are fairly forgiving to oddly-formed HTML, since a lot of Web pages are odd. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight change to your code. Use lazy approach.

```
.replaceAll("(<font.+?)\\S*color+.*?(>)","<span class=\"c2f\">");
```